# Voronoi edges example

Tags: geometry, infinity, computational-geometry, triangulation, voronoi-diagram

I have 4 line segments:

```
0 0 2 0 // 1st line segment
2 0 2 1 // 2nd line segment
2 1 0 1
0 1 0 0
```

and I wrote some [CGAL code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447998/how-to-print-edges-of-delanay-graph) to print the Voronoi edges. However, `infinite vertex` is being printed for some vertices, as indicated in this [example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Segment_Delaunay_graph_2/Segment_Delaunay_graph_2_2sdg-voronoi-edges_8cpp-example.html). However, our hw wants the output to be like this:

```
0 0 -1 0 // here I am printing 0 0 infinite vertex
0 0 0 -1
0 1 -1 1
2 1 3 1
2 0 2 -1
0 1 0.5 0.5
0 1 0 2
2 0 3 0
2 0 1.5 0.5
1.5 0.5 2 1
1.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
2 1 2 2
0 0 0.5 0.5
```

For example (Each oriented Voronoi edge (horizontal segment in the figure below) is defined by four sites A, B, C and D.), for the 1st edge, I know that the situation looks like this:

```
       \                     /
        \         B         /
         \                 /
       C  -----------------  D
         /                 \
        /         A         \
       /                     \
```

where:

```
A = poiint 0 0
B = line segment 0 1 0 0
C = infinite vertex
D = line segment 0 0 2 0
```

What should be done (conceptually) for `C` to be converted in `-1 0`?

---

*Edit*:

```
  The sites A and B define the (oriented) bisector on which the
  edge lies whereas the sites C and D, along with A and B define
  the two endpoints of the edge. These endpoints are the Voronoi
  vertices of the triples A, B, C and B, A, D.
  If one of these vertices is the vertex at infinity the string
  "infinite vertex" is printed; the corresponding Voronoi edge is
  actually a stright-line or parabolic ray.
```

Comment: How is the 4 x 4 array "these line segments"?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork does my edit help? Every row is a line segment, but I didn't really meant to imply a matrix being used there.

Comment: I have no idea what your representation is.  Is the first segment from coordinate $(0,0)$ to coordinate $(2,0)$, for instance?  And why would you ever represent graphics using text?!!!  Nobody has done that since 1970.  And your graphic is absolutely wrong:  the diagonal line should be MID-WAY between points B and C, and likewise for other pairs involving D and D.

Comment: **Yes** @DavidG.Stork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what a correct Voronoi tesselation looks like:

[image]